ASP.NET Core Web API - How to use XML formatter for a single endpoint while keeping JSON for others?
I have an ASP.NET Core Web API that primarily uses JSON for communication. However, I need one specific endpoint to handle XML requests and responses.
I've added a custom XmlSerializerOutputFormatter to my program.cs:
services.AddMvc(options =>
            {
                options.OutputFormatters.Clear(); 
                
                options.OutputFormatters.Add(new CustomXmlSerializerOutputFormatter()); 
            });

The problem is that now all my endpoints are treated as if they accept and produce XML and without It my xml endpoint doesn't work.
I tried to add
[Consumes("application/json")]
[Produces("application/json")]

to my json controlers but It doesn't help.
How can I fix it so my app will consume/produce json except for this one endpoint.

Turns out I needed to add
[HttpPost("itn.{format}"), FormatFilter]

To my endpoint, with this I don't need OutputFormatters.
Also you need to include the .xml extension in your request URL, like /api/shop/itn.xml
